# Android Studio 3 error: Local SDK path not set

Tags: android

When I try to run my app on emulator, this error pops up.

`Android Studio 3 error: Local SDK path not set`

I have tried syncing with gradle. My Sdk path is known and shows otherwise everywhere else in the studio

Comment: Please provide us the error you're getting.

Comment: provide the local.properties file please

Comment: I have the same problem. And the `local.properties` file is: `sdk.dir=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 8):

I got this error - the solution was to close the project and open it again.

Assuming:

- the sdk path in your File/SDK Location is correct
- all other build issues have been solved.

On Android Studio 3.1.2

Comment: Thank you - also on Android Studio 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, do following steps to solve:

1-Make sure in file "local.properties" sdk path set correctly: example:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/hamed{your own username}/Library/Android/sdk
```

if the sdk.dir shows the wrong sdk path change it to your correct path.

2-     Build: Clean your project

3-     Build: Rebuild

4-Close Android Studio and open it again

Error has gone :)